# How can I use the while loop correctly if there is two possible answer is acceptable?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I would like to ask the user to input the gender.
if the user's answer is not male or female, I want to loop the question again and again until the user enter male or female

here is what I wrote:

```
while not (mf):
    gender=input("Next, the gender of the character is (male/female):")
    if gender == ("male") or ("female"):
        mf=True
    else:
        print("Enter the correct gender type.")
```

if I enter female when asking gender, it would treat as wrong, but both female and male should be correct answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `while True`, which is commonly used:

```
while True:
    gender = input("Next, the gender of the character is (male/female):")
    if gender in ["male", "female"]:
        break
    print("Enter the correct gender type.")

print(gender)
```

Comment: thanks. A clear answer, help me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

The statment of `gender == ("male") or ("female")` is always true

change it into:
`gender in ['male', 'famale']`

## Explanation:

doing `gender == ("male") or ("female")`, there is two expressions here, one is 
`gender == ("male")` which is the right one, but after it comes the `or` keyword, which make the next thing a statement too, so the next statement is `('female')` which is a truly value, so it will always be true

Comment: okay, I get it. Thanks a lot for answering, i tried it for a long time.

Comment: @KITO no problem :) if you think it's the right answer you can mark it as currect (check nicolas answer too, its not really explaning the error, but its a good practice)

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest the below code to avoid using a new variable for the sake of storing if the input is correct, which you can directly check using the `gender` variable you're already using.

```py
gender = "" # initialize the variable
while not (gender in ['male', 'famale']):
  gender = input("Next, the gender of the character is (male/female):")
  if not gender in ['male', 'famale']:
    print("Enter the correct gender type.")
```